# Have Text in an Input Box Start X Pixels Over

Tags: html, css, textbox, spacing

So, I have an `input` box and it hugs the left side a lot because of my chosen font and because of the size customization and such. However, when you type in some text, it looks pretty icky because of this. All I want is to have there be some kind of thing I can change to change how far over the text in the text box actually starts (besides `left`, `center`, and `right`).

See my code below. Notice that when you type in the text box, it hugs the left side a bit and looks bad.

```css
.signatureInformationSign {
  color: #266AC3;
  font-family: 'Titillium Web', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 50px;
}
.editorTextInfo {
  color: #016F47;
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 50px;
  margin-top: 35px;
}
.editorTextBox {
  font-family: 'Hind', sans-serif;
  margin-top: 80px;
  font-size: 30px;
  height: 48px;
  width: 260px;
  border: 3px solid darkGray;
  border-radius: 18px;
}
.editorTextBox:focus {
  outline: 0;
}
input[type = "radio"]:after {
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  top: -12px;
  right: 6px;
  margin-right: 50px;
  background-color: darkGray;
  content: "";
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}
input[type = "radio"]:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}
input[type = "radio"]:checked:after {
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: orange;
  top: -12px;
  right: 6px;
  content: "";
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}
.editorPhoneBox {
  font-family: 'Hind', sans-serif;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  font-size: 16px;
  height: 22px;
  width: 28px;
  border: 2px solid darkGray;
  border-radius: 6px;
}
.editorPhoneBoxOther {
  font-family: 'Hind', sans-serif;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  font-size: 16px;
  height: 22px;
  width: 38px;
  border: 2px solid darkGray;
  border-radius: 6px;
}
.editorPhoneBox:focus, .editorPhoneBoxOther:focus {
  outline: 0;
}
#plusButton {
  color: gray;
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
  font-size: 32px;
  margin-top: -15px;
}
#plusButton:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>repl.it</title>
    <link href="index.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Hind|Source+Sans+Pro|Titillium+Web" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id = "question1">
      <center><div class = "signatureInformationSign">Signature Information Sign</div></center>
      <center><div class = "editorTextInfo">Name</div></center>
      <center><input type = "text" class = "editorTextBox"></center>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

P.S I don't care for your opinion as to whether or not it actually looks good, I just want a solution.

Comment: Add some padding to your .editorTextBox class For example; padding-left: 10px;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add a padding. Added left & right of the input box of `20px`;

```css
.signatureInformationSign {
  color: #266AC3;
  font-family: 'Titillium Web', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 50px;
}
.editorTextInfo {
  color: #016F47;
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 50px;
  margin-top: 35px;
}
.editorTextBox {
  font-family: 'Hind', sans-serif;
  margin-top: 80px;
  font-size: 30px;
  height: 48px;
  width: 260px;
  border: 3px solid darkGray;
  border-radius: 18px;
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-right: 20px;
}
.editorTextBox:focus {
  outline: 0;
}
input[type = "radio"]:after {
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  top: -12px;
  right: 6px;
  margin-right: 50px;
  background-color: darkGray;
  content: "";
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}
input[type = "radio"]:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}
input[type = "radio"]:checked:after {
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: orange;
  top: -12px;
  right: 6px;
  content: "";
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}
.editorPhoneBox {
  font-family: 'Hind', sans-serif;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  font-size: 16px;
  height: 22px;
  width: 28px;
  border: 2px solid darkGray;
  border-radius: 6px;
}
.editorPhoneBoxOther {
  font-family: 'Hind', sans-serif;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  font-size: 16px;
  height: 22px;
  width: 38px;
  border: 2px solid darkGray;
  border-radius: 6px;
}
.editorPhoneBox:focus, .editorPhoneBoxOther:focus {
  outline: 0;
}
#plusButton {
  color: gray;
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
  font-size: 32px;
  margin-top: -15px;
}
#plusButton:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>repl.it</title>
    <link href="index.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Hind|Source+Sans+Pro|Titillium+Web" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id = "question1">
      <center><div class = "signatureInformationSign">Signature Information Sign</div></center>
      <center><div class = "editorTextInfo">Name</div></center>
      <center><input type = "text" class = "editorTextBox"></center>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```